# Is there a way to make the square move continuously by just pressing 1 time?

Tags: python, pygame

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeVNm.png)

PROGRAMING LANGUAGE THAT I USE IS PYTHON

As on the photo,i have a character(square) and i want when i press the left, right, up, down keys, it has to keep moving in that direction until it hits the wall then stops.But when i press those keys, it only moves once and not continuously like i thought.how to make it move continuously

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#display
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
caption = pygame.display.set_caption('SwipeIt')
#player
square = pygame.image.load('asset/square.png').convert_alpha()
square_rect = square.get_rect(center = (100,150))
#wall
wall1 = pygame.image.load('asset/wall1.png').convert()
wall2 = pygame.image.load('asset/wall2.png').convert()
screw = pygame.image.load('asset/screw.png').convert()
white = (255,252,252)
gravity = 0.25
swipe = 0
loop = True
while loop:
   print(window)
   window.fill(white)
   #wall
   window.blit(wall1,(0,0))
   window.blit(wall2,(0,0))
   window.blit(wall2,(565,0))
   window.blit(wall1,(0,566))
   window.blit(screw,(0,0))
   window.blit(screw,(0,566))
   window.blit(screw,(565,0))
   window.blit(screw,(565,566))
   #player
   window.blit(square,(square_rect))

   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                   swipe += gravity
                   square_rect.centery += swipe
           if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                   swipe -= gravity
                   square_rect.centery -= swipe  
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   swipe += gravity
                   square_rect.centerx += swipe   
           if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                   swipe -= gravity
                   square_rect.centerx -= swipe
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           loop = False
   
   pygame.display.flip()
   pygame.display.update()
   clock.tick(120)
```

If you need, here is the link to download the files I have used .
''https://www.mediafire.com/file/ilogoklz3t9abpa/asset.rar/file''

Comment: save target movement in a variable, and then move based on this variable. If you detect a key press, change target variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a snake game before and how I did it is by using a variable called direction.

Here is a little snippet from it.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            direction = "up"
            
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            direction = "down"

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            direction = "right"

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            direction = "left"
```

Then I would check the current direction and change the position depending on the direction.

For example:

one would be

```
if direction == "up":
    player_y += 5
```

Comment: how to have that variable?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: how to make that variable called direction

Comment: ```direction = "right"``` right is just the default

Comment: thanks<3 it's working

Comment: No problem!  -----

Comment: @DanielYoffdan The common way is to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

Comment: I like this way better like this because its all in the beginning for the first check on the game loop. In other games where we don't need to make an object keep its direction